# Yii2. "With" in ManyToMany

Tags: php, yii2, database-relations

I have 3 models: Image, Company and File. So if we look through Company model, we have:

```
/**
* @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
*/
public function getImages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('galleries\models\Image', ['id' => 'image_id'])
        ->viaTable('{{%companies_has_images}}', ['company_id' => 'id']);
}

public function extraFields()
{
    return ['images'];
}
```

now an Image model:

```
    /**
* @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
*/
public function getFile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('app\models\File', ['id' => 'file_id']);
}

public function extraFields()
{
    return ['file'];
}
```

So here is the question, how can i get images with correct files in getImages() in the Company model?

Comment: Just use the relations? `foreach ($company->images as $image) $file = $image->file;` Your question is a somewhat unclear.

Comment: Thank you, i was needed something like
    public function getFileImage()
    {
        foreach ($this->images as $image) {
            $files[] = $image->file;
        } 

        return $files;
    }

Comment: If that is the information you are looking for, I'll write it in an answer so you can mark the question resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to fetch the images first and then provide an extra getter function to return the files:

```
public function getImageFiles() 
{
    $files = [];
    foreach ($this->images as $image)
       $files[] = $image->file;
    return $files;
}
```